# Make Test overlap in Flex box while reducing screen size

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to move to make new blog post header, Currently, it is being designed using different CSS but I am writing it using flexbox.

> [image: So this is how it looks like now]

I want to make similar thing in flex but the problem is when I reduce the screen size the picture become like this

> [image: this is after shrinking size of screen]

I want to achieve both this in flexbox. I am not sure if I can do that,

Comment: Please include the relevant code (As a [mcve])

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nipunbhardwaj/unb7jha3/ . Have a look at this fiddle. I want to achieve as displayed in image using flex

Comment: Flexbox has no property that will allow overlapping of elements. You need a different layout method.

Comment: Can you suggest something?